# easyinvoice npm package returns It retuns 'ThrottlerException: Too Many Requests'

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-package

I am using easyinvoice package and creating invoice it returns { statusCode: 429, message: 'ThrottlerException: Too Many Requests' }
so i purchased subscription and used the API key. but still throws same error. i have created invoice in local it worked but it also not reflected in budgect invoice portal

```
var data = {
    "apiKey": process.env.EASY_INVOICE_API_KEY, // Please register to receive a production apiKey: https://app.budgetinvoice.com/register
    "mode": "production",
    // Let's add a recipient
    "client": {
.........
    easyinvoice.createInvoice(data, function (result) {
    var pdf = result.pdf;
.........
}).catch(err=>{
        console.log(err); callback(null)
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I have chatted with support team we have to purchase subscription to avoid this. if we get this issue after purchasing try below things i have tried second option due to my code base.

1. Install the latest version of easy invoice
2. if ES6 is not supported in your code install 2.4.1
3. or you can use api for creating invoice

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).